# AngularJS NG-GRID callback needed

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I need to hide certain cells in a row depending on the value of the 2nd cell in the row. I have a cell template with an ng-hide passing in a function. The problem is the {{row.getProperty(\'occupied\')}} isn't rendered until after the ng-grid is done loading and the function is happening before. Is there a ng-grid call back function I can use?

```
$scope.hideInactive = function (checkSpot) {
                    if (checkSpot == 'Inactive') {
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                };

<div>
    <span ng-hide="hideInactive({{row.getProperty(\'occupied\')}})">
{{row.entity[col.field]}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Got kind of created and used the ng-class instead

    <div><span ng-class="{hide: row.getProperty(\'occupied\') == \'Inactive\'}">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</span></div>

Comment: If it starts getting too tricky, don't forget you can also clean your data prior to creating your grid. (Loop on it, remove the rows with unneeded data)